# Create JSON from map of json path/dot notation and value in java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a map of json path and its associated value. I want to create json using this path key and attach value at the end. Something like input as:

```
{key: "name1.name2.name3", value: "value1"},
{key:"name1.name2.name4", value: "value2"},
{key:"name1.name5[0]", value: "value3"},
{key:"name1.name5[1]", value: "value4"}
```

Output as:

```
{"name1":
   {"name2":
     {"name3":"value1",
      "name4":"value2"
     }
   },
   "name5":["value3","value4"]
}
```

There can be a list as well. Is there any library I can use?

Comment: Look at gson or jackson.

Comment: https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener ?

Comment: @tgdavies I am using jackson in my project but it doesn't provide any util for this. Not sure of gson but tried googling but couldn't find much for creating json.

Comment: @amantsingh this could work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Implemented the comment from @amant singh. https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

> Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> Test:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name1.name2.name3", "value1");
map.put("name1.name2.name4", "value2");
map.put("name1.name5[0]", "value3");
map.put("name1.name5[1]", "value4");

System.out.println(map);
String unflatten = JsonUnflattener.unflatten(map);
System.out.println(unflatten);
```

> Output:

```
{name1.name5[1]=value4, name1.name5[0]=value3, name1.name2.name3=value1, name1.name2.name4=value2}
{"name1":{"name5":["value3","value4"],"name2":{"name3":"value1","name4":"value2"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, long time ago in a company far away I used apache OGNL library that could do something like this. Here is the link: [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/). But also, today most JSON parsing is done with Jackson or Gson libs. Also a quick search in google "apache jsonpath library" gave some nice links. See this one: [JSONPath - Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html)

Comment: If I am not wrong, OGNL and Apache camel is more for reading value from object/json and not actually for creating the json object.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. But what I would try to do in general, I would try convert your input data, into a Map<String, Value> and then convert it into Json using any Json lib such as Jackson or Gson. I thought that OGNL can help you convert your input into standard map